# Searching for a unique word in a string

Tags: python

I almost write a program that can perform multiple task on GEDCOM file (file that hold information about your family tree).

I face only one problem though; there are some lines like this:

```
0 @F8@ FAM
1 FAMC @F5@
1 FAMS @F5@
```

Now I want to extract the code which starts from @ and ends with @.

I used:

```
 if 'FAM' in line:
     var = line[1:6]
     ...
```

But when I run the program it outputs all the lines with `FAMC` and `FAMS` as these words have `FAM` inside them.

How can I extract lines only matching `FAM`only? Thank you.

Comment: Please add your expected output

Comment: Did you tried using regular expression?

Comment: NO I havent tried regular expression

Comment: Example of doing this via regular expression in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a regular expression (word boundaries), and [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.search):

```
lines = [
    "0 @F8@ FAM",
    "1 FAMC @F5@",
    "1 FAMS @F5@"
]

for line in lines:
    if re.search(r'\bFAM\b', line):
        var = line
        print var
```

A "word boundary" (`\b`) marks the start or end of a word.

We can also use `re.search()` to extract the family code at the same time:

```
for line in lines:
    search = re.search(r'@([A-Z0-9]+)@\s*\bFAM\b', line)
    if search:
        code = search.group(1)
        print code
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
  for l in lines:
    for a in l:
      if(a[0]=="@" and a[-1]=="@"):
        print(a)
```